# elementary Abel function of a polynomial

Tags: fractional-iteration, functional-equations

Is there an elementary real function $F$ such that
$F(1+F^{-1}(x))$ is a polynomial of degree at least 2 without real fixpoints.

Comment: I don't know. Is there any use for such a function? Do you know an $F$ such that you get a polynomial of degree at least 2 with a real fixed point? 

Comment: Ya one gets the Chebychev polynomials $T_n$ of degree $n$ with
$F(x)=\cos(n^x)$. For example $\cos(2^{1+log_2(\arccos(x))})=\cos(2 \arccos(x))=2 x^2-1 = T_2(x)$. 


Comment: And I forgot to mention: All Chebychev polynomials have fixpoint 1.